# How Do We Show M Has a 1-Dimensional Atlas but Not Hausdorff?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

**Question:**

On $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus\{0\}$, introduce an equivalence relation by declaring that $(x,y)\sim (x^{\prime}, y^{\prime})$ if and only if there exists $t>0$ and that $x^{\prime} = tx$ and $y^{\prime} = y/t$. Let $M$ be the set of equivalence classes.

Show that $M$ has a natural $ 1-$ dimensional atlas, which is **NOT** Hausdorff. (Remark: Here, "Natural" means that if you sketch the equivalence classes, you will see a way to choose little transverse arcs that suggest a $1-$dimensional atlas.)

I thought of this as a projective space $\mathbb{R}P^n$, but I do not know how to attack this question. I am not sure I can sketch the equivalence classes, either. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $t'$ seems out of place.

Comment: @gpassante I just edited the question. We are supposed to have $y^{\prime}$ instead of $t^{\prime}$. So, how should I attack this question?

Comment: The equivalences of $(x_1,y_1)$ is a branch of the hyperbole of equation $XY = x_1y_1$

Comment: Hint: Analyze neighborhoods of the equivalence classes of $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Every point of the form $(t,0)$ is equivalent to $(1,0)$, and every point of the form $(0, 1/t)$ is equivalent to $(0,1)$. Since $S^1\subseteq  \mathbb{R}^2$, I am thinking of saying $P^1(\mathbb{R}) := S^1/\sim$. Is this a valid approach? How can I make the best use of $[(t,0)]$ and $[(0,1/t)]$?

Comment: This problem has absolutely nothing to do with projective space of any dimension.

Comment: @MoisheKohan any insight you can give would be highly appreciated. I don’t seem to know how to solve this.

Comment: I can only repeat my hint above. You did not analyze neighborhoods as I suggested.

Comment: @MoisheKohan $[(1,0)]$ gives us the whole of the positive x-axis without the origin. $[(0,1)]$ gives us the whole of the positive y-axis without the origin. Now, $[(1,1)]$ gives us an arc that approaches both positive axes but never touches them. This arc is concentric with $[(2,2)]$, $[(3,3)]$ etc in the first quadrant. We can do the same in other quadrants. So, we will have the other axes without the origin, and the concentric arcs in every quadrant as well. I don’t know how to show that M has a 1-dimensional atlas which is not Hausdorff from here. Your help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You do not seem to know what the word "neighborhood" means. My suggestion is to review the basic general topology.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I guess by neighborhood, we mean what is happening in an open set centred at the point of interest. Maybe I can’t link the concept of neighbourhood to equivalent classes

Comment: As I said, you do not have a good grasp of general topology. You should review some basics including quotient topology. Otherwise, you will never be able to solve such problems.